# COVID map using a mapbox API

Tags: javascript, fetch, mapbox

```
const getColor = count => {
    if (count > 1000000) {
        return "yellow";
    } else if (count >= 1500000) {
        return "red";
    } else {
        return "green";
    }
}
fetch("countryPosition.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        countries = data.ref_country_codes;
        //console.log(countries); //lista obiektów z countryPos.
        countries.forEach(country => {
           
            new mapboxgl.Marker({
                    color: "red"
                   //color: getColor(placeInfected.TotalConfirmed)
                }).setLngLat([country.longitude, country.latitude])
                .addTo(map)
        })      
    })
fetch(summary_url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(respond => {
            places = respond.Countries
           // console.log(places.Country); //lista obiektów z API 
            places.forEach(place => {
                
            })           
        })
```

I've created a map using Mapbox, added markers on every country(coordinates from that JSON file) and now I want to change the marker color depending on the number of infected people, which I get from summary_url, but I can't figure out how to do it. I am a beginner in Javascript, so if you can please help.

Comment: Are you saying you want `Marker({ color: "red" })` to be dynamic?

Comment: No, just simple if selection in function getColor. I have to check if CountryID from Object list in summary_url is equal with Country ID from Object list in countryPosition.json, IF yes then the infected count( this is the TotalConfirmed of country from summary_url) have to be an argument in function getColor. I don't know how to get out a date from this  fetches

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by "don't know how to get out a date from this fetches." You mean you don't know how to combine both results from fetches and **then** do whatever you need to do?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: You should use `Promise.all()` then, e.g. `Promise.all([fetch("countryPosition.json"), fetch(summary_ur")]).then(([countryPosition, summaryUrl]) => {...})`. See [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try that

Comment: I made that! but i got an error's because probably some of the countryID's aren't equal and it return undefined, so it can't read a lan&lat. Do you have any idea how to filter it ?

Comment: http://wklejto.pl/880516
There is a code

Comment: What is the common property inside `places` and `reports` that you can use to combine your data? `alpha2` inside `places` and `placeId` inside `reports`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your geoJSON source has a property that defines the color, you can add a [SymbolLayer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#circle), instead of markers.

SymbolLayer circles color can be adjusted, similar to in this example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/

If you want to stick with markers, you can choose to display different icons, based on a property value from your geoJSON source file. However, that is more work.

Markers only allows for showing custom icons, that could be colored.

This is how to add custom icons to a markers:

(make sure to have the bitmap.bmp in your working directory)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add custom icons with Markers</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .marker {
        display: block;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
    // ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
    // https://account.mapbox.com
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
    var geojson = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
            {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {
                    'message': 'Foo',
                    'iconSize': [60, 60]
                },
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [-66.324462890625, -16.024695711685304]
                }
            },
            {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {
                    'message': 'Bar',
                    'iconSize': [50, 50]
                },
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [-61.2158203125, -15.97189158092897]
                }
            },
            {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {
                    'message': 'Baz',
                    'iconSize': [40, 40]
                },
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [-63.29223632812499, -18.28151823530889]
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-65.017, -16.457],
        zoom: 5
    });

    // add markers to map
    geojson.features.forEach(function (marker) {
        // create a DOM element for the marker
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';
        el.style.backgroundImage =
            'url(./bitmap.bmp)';
        el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
        el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

        el.addEventListener('click', function () {
            window.alert(marker.properties.message);
        });

        // add marker to map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            
            .addTo(map);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```